# Split character string into three columns when number of pieces differs between rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame similar to the following reprex:

```
test <- data.frame(
  age = c("6 hours", "2 days, 4 hours", "1 months3 days, 7 hours")
)
```

Unfortunately, as you can see by row 3, the three pieces of the string are not all separated by a comma.

My intended output is as follows:

```
                        age agem aged ageh
1                   6 hours   NA   NA   6
2           2 days, 4 hours   NA    2   4
3 1 months3 days, 7 hours      1    3   7
```

I have tried using `dplyr::separate` like this

```
new_test <- test %>%
  separate(age, c("agem", "ageh", "aged"), sep = "[^[\\d]]+", convert = TRUE,
           remove = FALSE, fill = "left")
```

This works great for the entries with just 'hours', but if there are 'days and hours' or 'months, days and hours', then the order of the output is wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str_extract`from the package `stringr` and positive lookahead in `(?= ...)`:

```
test$agem <- str_extract(test$age, "\\d+(?=\\smonth)")
test$aged <- str_extract(test$age, "\\d+(?=\\sday)")
test$ageh <- str_extract(test$age, "\\d+(?=\\shour)")
```

Result:

```
test
                      age agem aged ageh
1                 6 hours <NA> <NA>    6
2         2 days, 4 hours <NA>    2    4
3 1 months3 days, 7 hours    1    3    7
```

Comment: A very simple and elegant solution that worked perfectly, thank you. Apologies for the delay but I have now marked this as the accepted answer as, although both posted solutions worked, this was the one I used and was also the most succinct.

Answer (score 3):

First, include a separator wherever there is none between alphabetic characters and numeric digits. Then `tidyr::separate` into columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>%
  mutate(age = gsub("([[:alpha:]])([[:digit:]])", "\\1, \\2", age)) %>%
  separate(age, into = c('agem', 'aged', 'ageh'), 
           sep = ', ',
           convert = TRUE,
           remove = FALSE, fill = "left") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches('age[[:alpha:]]')), function(x) as.numeric(gsub('[^[:digit:]]', '', x)))
#                        age agem aged ageh
#1                   6 hours   NA   NA    6
#2           2 days, 4 hours   NA    2    4
#3 1 months, 3 days, 7 hours    1    3    7
```

Comment: Great solution. @Sam, if you need to remove the text part of the new columns, one way is to use parse_number from library readr.

Comment: Text part is not included in expected outcome